# questions on selling a product similar to a patent

Tags: infringement

In reference to the patent: [US8317762](https://www.google.com/patents/US8317762)

I am looking to sell a product online but a similar product has a patent for it. How can i sell a product that wont break the patent law?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably confident that the technology described in this patent is junk and wouldn't work to an extent that has a useful health benefit. That said, if you want to make something similar you simply need to avoid some aspect of the claims. Here is the first claim:

> 1. A skin patch for absorbing toxins from a body comprising:
>
>    a first side comprising a heat reflective foil comprising titanium;
>
>    a second
>      side comprising a non-woven rayon surface configured for absorbing and
>      retaining the toxins, said rayon surface comprising a plurality of
>      openings configured for enhancing transmission of far infrared ray
>      emission into a skin when said second side is placed in contact with
>      the skin; 
>      and
>
>    a mixture of natural ingredients consisting of, by
>      weight, 24% vinegar, 0.8% chitosan, 0.8% loquat leaf, 0.8% houttuynia
>      cordata, 0.8% vitamin C, 60% tourmaline, 4% vegetable fiber, and 8.8%
>      dextrin, said mixture formulated to emit said far infrared ray
>      emission, whereby blood circulation is promoted and perspiration and
>      any toxins contained therein are absorbed by said rayon surface.

For instance, you could use a foil not containing titanium or a different mixture of chemicals. Just don't expect your product to have any efficacy. If you make health claims, you will probably violate other laws depending on your country.